# $x = 2^{\log_57}$ and $y = 7^{\log_52}$ find $x - y$

Tags: logarithms

Wolfram Alpha says the answer is zero. But how to find the value of $x - y$ when the bases aren't even same. I know that $K^{\log_K x}= x.$

Comment: Hint: Try showing $x=y$ by proving $\log_5(x) = \log_5(y)$.

Comment: @Andreas Gotcha, both x and y are indeed same in my problem. Each being [log7 * log 2] / log 5. Thanks.

Comment: What is $\log[x,y]?$ Is it $\log_xy$ or $\log_yx,$ or something else?

Comment: Hint: $$\log_b c=\frac{\log_ac}{\log_ab}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show that $a^{\log_bc}=c^{\log_ba}$ for any positive $a$, $b$ and $c$. Indeed,
$$a^{\log_b c}=\left(b^{\log_ba}\right)^{\log_b c}=\left(b^{\log_bc}\right)^{\log_b a}=c^{\log_ba}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$x = 2^{log_5(7)} = 5^{log_5(2^{log_5(7)})} = 5^{log_5(7)log_5(2)}$

$ = 5^{log_5(2)log_5(7)} = 5^{log_5(7^{log_5(2)})} $

$ = 7^{log_5(2)} = y$

---

Another method

$x = 2^{log_5(7)} = 2^{\frac{ln(7)}{ln(5)}} = e^{ln(2^{(\frac{ln(7)}{ln(5)})})}$

$ = e^{{\frac{ln(2)ln(7)}{ln(5)}}} = e^{ln(7^{(\frac{ln(2)}{ln(5)})})}$

$ = 7^{\frac{ln(2)}{ln(5)}} = 7^{log_5(2)} = y$

---

Hence, $x = y$

$x-y = 0$

Answer (score 1):

$\large x=2^\frac{\ln 7}{\ln 5}\qquad → \ln(x) = \left(\frac{\ln 7}{\ln 5}\right) (\ln 2)$
$\large y=7^\frac{\ln 2}{\ln 5}\qquad → \ln(y) = \left(\frac{\ln 2}{\ln 5}\right) (\ln 7)$

(x,y) have same log value, thus $\;x-y = x-x = 0$